# I open jupyter on Anaconda3 and appear kernel error, what i do?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In the kernel error appears  this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 476, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 141, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Users\A0165\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in **enter**
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 404, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "C:\Users\A0165\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 359, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontró el proceso especificado.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got same error on Windows10 x86_64bit with Python3.7-32bit or Python3.8-64bit environment. In my case, the mismatch of bit and version seemed to be the root cause. At first I uninstalled all the Python versions and Anaconda, then re-installed them again as following, then the kernel error disappeared on junyper-notebook.

Windows10 x86_64bit
Python3.7.5-64bit
Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64

*Anaconda seems to use \Python37\ path as default so my Python3.8 didn't work well. I don't know how to change the path to Python38.

Answer (score 0):

Like sshinobu, I recently got this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393239/jupyter-notebook-anaconda-kernel-error-idiot-proof-fix?noredirect=1#comment106835589_60393239).

Short version - It went away after running Anaconda-Navigator, and if needed Anaconda Prompt in administrator mode. Hope that fixes it for you