# Jupyter Notebook / Anaconda 'Kernel Error' (Idiot Proof Fix)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, jupyter

I recently installed Anaconda 3 / Jupyter on my Windows 10 machine, and it is reliably showing 'Kernel Error' in the top right. 
The code I'm trying to run is a simple fitting code (Available here: `<https://pastebin.com/0TBegxGa>` (though it won't work without the data, might give some help as to what I'm trying to do)), that was originally written on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine, where the tools downloaded with Anaconda3 worked fine. Due to the virtual machine being fairly unreliable and crashing a lot, I decided to move things across to my Windows machine and continue there, but on installing Anaconda and launching a Jupyter Notebook, I get the Kernel Error issue.

Error Readout is shown below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py",
>   line 1699, in _execute
>       result = await result
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py",
>   line 72, in post
>       type=mtype))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
>   line 88, in create_session
>       kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
>   line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
>       self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 209, in wrapper
>       yielded = next(result)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py",
>   line 168, in start_kernel super(MappingKernelManager,
>   self).start_kernel(**kwargs)   File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py",
>   line 110, in start_kernel
>       km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py",
>   line 240, in start_kernel
>       self.write_connection_file()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
>   line 547, in write_connection_file
>       kernel_name=self.kernel_name
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
>   line 212, in write_connection_file
>       with secure_write(fname) as f:
>
> File "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\contextlib.py", line
>   112, in **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Anaconda3_1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
>   line 102, in secure_write
>       with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
>   ++'C:\Users\ControlRoom6\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-d48826e3-1503-4c3a-b3ff-d461b3054c0a.json'

I'm aware there are similiar questions out there like this, but the solutions either seem for other versiosn or I can't really understand what the solution is asking the poster to do, so I can't enact it (I'm completely new to this stuff, so an idiot proof step-by-step would be really appreciated if possible). Many solutions mention creating environment or entering commands, but I'm not too sure how to do this / where this command entering should be done? (Anaconda Prompt?)

Thanks for any help

Comment: If I had to guess, you've installed Anaconda in a directory that you don't have read permissions to, possibly set by the IT team

Comment: The question about the same error message, asked 6 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387526/error-13-when-trying-to-run-my-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Thanks for the reply - whilst it is a work machine it's a lab computer so basically it comes out the box with no additional IT monitoring. It seems to be installed in C:\Users\Anaconda3_1, which according to the properties security tab - I have full read & write permissions for.

Comment: Tsyvarev, thank you - running Anaconda itself as administrator has fixed the kernel error issue. I hadn't seen that question among the ones I had found. Much appreciated. 

I get: 'File "<ipython-input-1-7ba1e83eaa7f>", line 19
    base = 'C:\Users\ControlRoom6\Documents\PhD\Ubuntu-Analysis-DCF\DCF-an-b+decay\dcp-ap-27Al\Run15\'
                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal' now, but that sounds far more like something to do with my code in the transfer to Windows.